# How to get unique combinations that don't have repeating number if only given two integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers, range

I have a list consisting of two numbers:

```
[0, 3]
```

The first number is the starting number and the second number is the ending number. I want to find all the unique combinations of numbers in that range so that the first number is not the same as the second number. E.g:

```
[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3]
```

I can't seem to find a similar solution online. I've seen using itertools but it doesn't apply in my situation. How would you do this in Python? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `itertools.combinations(range(l[0],l[1]+1), r=2)`

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Nick cheers for the reply, I have tried with your line but it doesn't print me anything when I did print(itertools.combinations(range(l[0],l[1]+1), r=2))

Comment: @JesseLingLing I've assumed you have defined `l = [0,3]`. then you would `print([t for t in itertools.combinations(range(l[0],l[1]+1), r=2)])` (note you need a comprehension otherwise you'll just get something like `<itertools.combinations object at 0x000002939C96CE50>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import itertools
result = list(itertools.combinations([0, 1, 2, 3], 2))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, I have a list only consisting of two numbers instead of having all the numbers in a list.

Comment: Can you share your desired output?

Comment: Hi I've sorted mine. I used what Nick above suggested: print([t for t in itertools.combinations(range(l[0],l[1]+1), r=2)]). Which returned me a list of tuples in the same form as your solution. But thanks anyway!